# Why is it "c'était il y a longtemps" and not "ça a été il y a longtemps"?

Tags: temps-grammatical, indications-de-temps, imparfait, espagnol

In Spanish we write "eso fue hace mucho tiempo" (preterite). Why do we use the *imparfait* tense it French?

Answer (score 4):

La formule « c'était il y a longtemps » est beaucoup utilisée, et elle sonne mieux que « ça a été il y a longtemps », qui n'est pas très belle, et pas correcte. À la place, tu peux dire « ça s'est passé il y a longtemps », ce serait à peu près la même chose. « C'était il y a longtemps » implique qu'on décrit une action qui était en train de se faire, sans délimitation fixe de l'événement, alors que « ça s'est passé il y a longtemps » indique plus un événement délimité. Par exemple :

> J'étais bon en grammaire, c'était il y a longtemps.
>
> Il m'a mis une sacrée raclée, ça s'est passé il y a longtemps.

Comment: Plus un pour l'exemple !